# An internet series - Heroine caught up with hackers and paramilitary organizations

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, cyberpunk

I remember so many details about this series except for the name. It was made about 10 years ago, I was really young don't remember, but it was about a woman who lived in The Federation which was basically a post-revolution china. She gets caught up with hackers and paramilitary organizations as she blasts across the globe from the hacker nations such as Iceland, to the radioactive cratered American east coast (everything across the Mississippi was fine), to an airship, to the agrarian post soviet states, back to a tea house in the federation.

Hackers, explosions, a bad-ass sidekick dude named Brain (I THINK), a police state, a conspiracy involving the virtual internet that you jack in to and secret servers that could simulate wind on your face, and AIs.